# how to add serial number in posted sale invoice report in rdlc

Tags: dynamic

how to add serial number in posted sale invoice serial no should start from 1 and  when we enter new line it increment serial no by report in rdlc

serial number in posted sale invoice report in rdlc in dynamic 365 business central AL